# Ritz Variational Method

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, atomic-physics, variational-principle

I want to use the Ritz Variational method to find a good approximation ground state and ground state energy for the hydrogen atom.

For that purpose I take two different ansatzes, do the machinery of the Ritz variational method and then I compare the results.

The ansatzes are:
a) $\psi_A(\vec{r})=e^{-Ar}$ and
b) $\psi_A(\vec{r})=\frac{1}{A^2+r^2}$

Ok, I started in both cases with the following idea. The functions in a) and b) are trial wavefunctions. Hence they must be normalized. In a) there is no problem, but in b) I have problems, because the integral does not converge. I want to show you my procedure:

Normalization factor should be $N$. The following must be hold:

$$1=\langle\psi_A(\vec{r})|\psi_A(\vec{r})\rangle$$

Using spherical coordinates we get the following integral (assuming $N$ is real):

$$1=N^2\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{A^2+r^2}\sin(\theta)r^2drd\theta d\phi$$

It is well-known that the inner integral does not converge. So the question is:

Is the procedure generally wrong or is the ansatz just not usable for the task to find a good approxmation.

Comment: A vector state is an element from an Hilbert space, and therefore it must have a finite 2-norm. If this is not the case then the wavefunction you have chosen is not representing a valid state

Comment: You forgot to square the wavefunction inside the integral.

Comment: @Dominik That's it. Thanks for your comment. The easiest mistakes are the most diffucult problem.